# printing number of snmpwalk results

Tags: python, perl, snmp, cacti

Were trying to make a script on a Ubuntu server that reads the number of results from an snmpwalk command, and then sending it to Cacti for graphing.

Since none of us have any kind of programming knowledge and from what we have tried, we havent succeed.

It will go like this:

the script runs: `snmpwalk -v 1 -c public -Cp 10.59.193.141 .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1`

The command will print

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.0.34.250.121.174.124 = Hex-STRING: 00 22 FA 79 AE 7C
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.0.35.20.11.246.64 = Hex-STRING: 00 23 14 0B F6 40
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.0.38.198.89.34.192 = Hex-STRING: 00 26 C6 59 22 C0
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.40.224.44.221.222.148 = Hex-STRING: 28 E0 2C DD DE 94
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.100.163.203.10.120.83 = Hex-STRING: 64 A3 CB 0A 78 53
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.120.214.240.8.133.165 = Hex-STRING: 78 D6 F0 08 85 A5
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.132.0.210.179.213.93 = Hex-STRING: 84 00 D2 B3 D5 5D
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.132.0.210.201.8.196 = Hex-STRING: 84 00 D2 C9 08 C4
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.140.112.90.108.236.188 = Hex-STRING: 8C 70 5A 6C EC BC
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.140.112.90.139.18.244 = Hex-STRING: 8C 70 5A 8B 12 F4
iso.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.6.4.1.1.8.1.1.2.1.180.240.171.112.37.69 = Hex-STRING: B4 F0 AB 70 25 45
Variables found: 11
```

Then the script should somehow do: read until Variables found: and read "11", and then print "11".

So basically we want the script to filter out the number "11" in this case which we can use in Cacti for graphing. We've tried some scripts on google and looked around for information, but found nothing.

I think it should be easy if you know how to do it, but we are beginners at programming.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `perl`, add following command after a pipe to extract the number you want:

```
... | perl -ne 'm/\A(?i)variables\s+/ and m/(\d+)\s*$/ and printf qq|%s\n|, $1 and exit'
```

It will print:

```
11
```